# Sending and receiving units from other methods

Tags: java, function, methods, netbeans

Can a single method receive more than 2 integers from other methods so it can perform a function?in method game I'm trying to receive the amount of edamage and elife from enemy methods and also trying to receive the user's life and damage from method user, so that method game has all the information so i can perform arithmetic functions of the user interacting with the enemy

```
    public static void game(String[] args, int elife) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int life=80;
    int damage = 8;
    int A = (elife - damage);
    String enemy ="";
    int Enemy;
    Random generator = new Random();
    Enemy = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 
        if (Enemy == 1) 
        {enemy = "Grunt";
            int hp=45;
        int shp= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());}
        else if (Enemy == 2) 
        {enemy = "Slave";
            int hp =40; }
        else if (Enemy == 3) 
        {enemy= "Witch";
        int hp=50;}
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game!");
    user();
    System.out.println("Get Ready to face you first opponent ");
    System.out.println("You are Faced against " + enemy);
    System.out.println("Would you like to: \n [A]Attack         [B]Defend");
    String choice = br.readLine();
    if (choice.equals("A")){
        System.out.println(""+A+"");
        System.out.println("You chose to attack "+enemy+" for "+"damage!");}
    else if(choice.equals("B")){
        System.out.println("You chose to defend and recieved"+"damage.");
}}
public static void user () throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int life= 80;
    int damage = 8;
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("WELCOME "+name); 
}


public static void Witch() throws IOException{   
    int elife = 50;
    int damage;    
    int edamage = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    damage = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 
        if (damage == 1) 
    edamage = 5; 
        else if (damage == 2) 
    edamage = 10; 
        else if (damage == 3) 
    edamage = 12; 
    System.out.println("Enemy life : "+elife);
    System.out.println("Enemy damage : " +edamage);
}
}
public static void Grunt(){   
    int elife = 45;
    int damage;    
    int edamage = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    damage = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 
        if (damage == 1) 
    edamage = 3; 
        else if (damage == 2) 
    edamage = 8; 
        else if (damage == 3) 
    edamage = 15; 
    System.out.println("Enemy life : "+elife);
    System.out.println("Enemy damage : " +edamage);
}   
public static void Slave(){  
    int elife = 40;
    int damage;    
    int edamage = 0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    damage = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 
        if (damage == 1) 
    edamage = 7; 
        else if (damage == 2) 
    edamage = 8; 
        else if (damage == 3) 
    edamage = 5; 
    System.out.println("Enemy life : "+elife);
    System.out.println("Enemy damage : " +edamage);
}}
```

Comment: Your talking about overloading? Make a method with same name, just different parameters?

Comment: If overloading is putting a bunch of info into just one method then yes also yes on the parameters. is it possible?

Comment: hmm.. good search terms are Gold !

Answer (score 2):

Method overloading (also known as static Polymorphism) is a way you can have two (or more) methods (functions) with same name in a single class. Yes its as simple as that.

```
public class Shape{
//It could be a circle or rectangle or square
private String type;
//To calculate area of rectangle
public Double area(Long length, Long breadth){
return (Double) length * breadth;
}
//To calculate area of a circle
public Double area(Long radius){
return (Double) 3.14 * r * r;
}
}
```

This way you can call the same method for area depending on the type of shape it has

Comment: i don't think the code you sent me is related to the question because i was asking about sending and recieving multiple integers from method to method. and i won't be calling methods

Comment: Tom has a good example of an overloaded method (Polymorphism). Methods are known as many things ie Functions, procedure etc. 

Your questions: "Can a single method receive more than 2 integers from other methods", Yes, you can call another method within another method and return what you want etc.

Comment: @Jonathan Just a thought, reviewing your code, you could create global variables so that way you can get/set life/damage and check them in your game method.